# Changing circle color in line chart using mpandroid

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to listen for the click on a particular circle on the line chart so that its (the clicked circle's) color gets changed on click.

Here is what I tried:

```
LineDataSet  set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet 1");

@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, int i) {
    set1.setCircleColorHole(Color.GREEN);  
}
```

What is currently happening is that, on click, all the circles' color is changing. What should happen is that only the circle that has been clicked - its color should change.

Comment: I have virtually no idea at all about android, but it looks like you call `setFillColor` for the whole data set, instead of a single item.

Comment: But how to set circlecolorhole for a single entity?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently setting the colour for `set1` which is the entire dataset. This is why you report that *all the circles' color is changing*. You need to do this but for a single entity.

According to the documentation for [OnChartValueSelectedListener](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.6/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartValueSelectedListener.html), the method `onValueSelected` can be overridden to contain an extra parameter, `Highlight`. *Disclaimer* I have never used this graphing library before so it may take some experimentation.

Taken directly from the source code for `chart` found here (line 562 at the time of writing):

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java

```
 /**
 * Highlights the values represented by the provided Highlight object
 * This DOES NOT generate a callback to the OnChartValueSelectedListener.
 *
 * @param highlight contains information about which entry should be highlighted
 */
public void highlightValue(Highlight highlight) {
    highlightValue(highlight, false);
}
```

Theoretically this will highlight the value selected. The other methods which do similar things have the following signatures:

`public void highlightValue(int xIndex, int dataSetIndex)`

`public void highlightValues(Highlight[] highs)`

`public void highlightValue(Highlight high, boolean callListener)`